# configuration options used in ubuntu 16 apache2 package

Tags: configuration, apache2

I want to compile Apache2 from source, making it like the ubuntu 16 package in all but one configuration option (version of openssl).  How can I discover what options the package was built with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`apt-get source apache2` gets you the precise sources used to package it.  Recompiling the package with one option changed would just require you to pass in that configuration option in the `debian/rules` file and repackage (though of course you should also do the usual motions to produce a unique local version number for the package).